# Cannot get the 'New value' of a 'changed' TD cell in table

Tags: jquery, html, flask, html-table

I need to store the existing data and changed data in variables to use in an AJAX/JQuery call to the database.

I can store the existing value using the onclick method.

However, I cannot seem to find any information about the onchange event for a table > tr > td cell.

I have tried quite researching this a lot, using delegates, everything, but I cannot find any information regarding the td change event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mytab:has(td)").click(function(e) {
        var clickedCell= $(e.target).closest("td");
        jQuery.data( div, "lastchange", clickedCell.text() );
    });
});
```

And that all works fine, but I cannot find anything for change, or on change and there must be something?

Answer (score 0):

Only input elements have onchange events. TD does not. You need to go beyond jQuery to do this type of thing, using **Angular** or **React** that supports actual data models and mutation events.

Comment: Using Flask I think that's an issue.  I am guessing I could simply put text inputs into the TD's but it's not a really nice clean solution.  However, I was thinking there wasn't a way.

Thanks